# When using `xfrm` and strongswan for an ipsec tunnel, where are the routes stored?

Tags: ipv6, ipsec, strongswan

I am using strongswan to establish an ipsec connection in tunnel mode. When the client connects to the gateway, strongswan receives a new ipv6 address assigned to the client from the server. All traffic send to the tunneled network is then send from this ip6 address.
The ipv6 address is assigned to the client's `wlp61s0` interface as, for example,`2222:33:8085:cf0:1:2:f6e5:a5d0/128`. My understanding of the `xfrm state` and the `xfrm policy` command is that they only store information about the security Associations (SA) and policies respectively, which select the used SA *based on* the source and destination address.

But how does the client kernel know that when the client sends information to the target network, e.g. `2222::/16`, that it should use a certain source address? And where can I retrieve this information about the current routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/howtos/introduction.html#_routing tells:

> On Linux, strongSwan installs routes into routing table 220 by default
> and hence requires the kernel to support policy based routing.

(And it's also using priority 220 to lookup table 220.)

So for IPv6 this should be seen with:

```
ip -6 rule show priority 220
```

or

```
ip -6 rule show lookup 220
```

for the policy routing part.

plus:

```
ip -6 route show table 220
```

for the routing table part.

To know what decision is taken by the kernel without having to think about it, one can ask the kernel what would be the decision. For example:

```
ip route get to 2222::1
```

will tell among other pieces of information the chosen source address, the chosen interface, the gateway if any and (if not the main table) the chosen routing table.

Please also note that IPv6 has a quite complex but well documented way to select source addresses when not explicitly overridden in (main) routes, routing rules/routing tables: [RFC 6724: Default Address Selection for Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6) 5.  Source Address Selection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6724.html#section-5)

Comment: `ip route get` doesn't seem to consider XFRM policies though. The added route seems to be optional: it's only needed for the src address when a packet for the remote IPsec network is being sent while the "via" part is disregarded.

Comment: @Kentzo - Right that `ip route get` doesn't consider XFRM policies. IP routing and the security infrastructure operate independently.  Note  how "routing decision" and "xfrm lookup" are separate in https://thermalcircle.de/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=linux:netfilter-packet-flow.png .  Adding further confusion, "ip routing" includes "ip rule" (which can be based on marks), but "xfrm lookup" does not include "ip rule" (and can also be based on marks.)  Marks aren't involved in this post, but can be used with xfrm/strongswan.